# Geometric intuition of flatness of completion

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $R$ be a ring and $I$ be an ideal of $R$. Let $\widehat{R}$ be a $I$-adic completion of $R$. It is known that $\widehat{R}$ is a flat $R$-module. Is there any geometric intuition for this fact?

For example, let $R = k[X_{1}, \dots, X_{n}]$ and $I = (X_{1}, \dots, X_{n})$, so that $\widehat{R} = k[[X_{1}, \dots, X_{n}]]$. In this case, $\mathrm{Spec}(R) = \mathbb{A}_{k}^{n}$. What is $\mathrm{Spec}(\widehat{R})$, and is there any explanation for why $\mathrm{Spec}(\widehat{R})\to \mathbb{A}_{k}^{n}$ is flat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my vague intuition : You can imagine this scheme as a formal open disk around zero, and open immersion are flat.

More generally I believe you can interpret the spectrum of the completion as a "formal neighborhood" of $Z(I)$ in $\text{Spec}(R)$. There is probably something about it in Hartshorne, in the section about formal schemes.

Comment: I heard that flatness is a sort of continuously varying fibers, am I right? In this sense, open immersion of a formal open disk has continuously varying fibers, so it seems to be a flat morphism.

Comment: @SeewooLee : yes exactly. For example, if your morphism is projective it means that the Hilbert polynomial of the fibers is constant.

Comment: Then it will be a possible explanation why projectiveness implies flatness. Thanks!

Comment: @SeewooLee : I'm not sure I understand your last comment, a projective morphism is not flat in general (for example a blow-up). But when this is the case, fibers have the same Hilbert polynomials which is (I think) the algebraic version of "continously varying fibers" as you said.